# How to group text columns into one column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need something like :

```
SELECT dt, (???) AS C FROM (SELECT dt,c1,c2,c3,c4  ...
```

dt - datetime and by the way I've got some weird structure , for example :

```
24.02.2011 null null null "text"
25.02.2011 null "te" null "text"
26.02.2011 null "te" null null
```

it must became

```
24.02.2011 "text"
25.02.2011 "te"
25.02.2011 "text"
26.02.2011 "te"
```

or maybe

```
24.02.2011 "c4" "text"
25.02.2011 "c2" "te"
25.02.2011 "c4 "text"
26.02.2011 "c2" "te"
```

if I do `select dt, с1+с2+с3+с4 as C from select dt,c1,c2,c3,c4`

there will be

```
25.02.2011  "tetext"
```

This output is INCORRECT for me.

it must be

```
25.02.2011 "te"
25.02.2011 "text"
```

so I need any idea how can I exchange rows+columns to rows.

thank you.

MS SQL Server 2008.

My current idea is create temporary or even maybe static table with structure I need and Insert data then select to / from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would probably be with UNION ALL:

```
SELECT dt,'c1' as Col,c1 from table1 where c1 is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT dt,'c2' as Col,c2 from table1 where c2 is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT dt,'c3' as Col,c3 from table1 where c3 is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT dt,'c4' as Col,c4 from table1 where c4 is not null
```

It's that awkward middle row of your sample data (that is meant to produce two output rows) that means that solutions using COALESCE/ISNULL are probably doomed.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know how this is in MS SQL server
But in mysql you could see this functions
[ifnull](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull), 
[if](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)